# To access class attribute using Prototype JS

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function Popup() {

}

Popup.prototype.openPopup = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("test");
    div.style.display = 'block';
        };

Popup.prototype.closePopup = function() {
var div = document.getElementById("test");
div.style.display = 'none';
};


window.onload = function() {
    var popup = new Popup();

    var opnpopup = document.getElementsByClassName('clck');
    opnpopup.addEventListener('click', function() {
        popup.openPopup();
    });

    var cnclpopup = document.getElementById('cancel');
    cnclpopup.addEventListener('click', function() {
        popup.closePopup();
    });


}
```

HTML code :

```
<button id="clck" class="clck">click here</button>
<div id="test" class="popup">
    This is a test message
    <div id="cancel" class="cancel" ></div>
</div>
```

In above js when i access the class name `'clck'` by using `document.getElementsByClassName('clck')` the popup is not displayed but when we access it through 'id' then it works..So whats the issue please explain

Comment: Are you sure you're using PrototypeJS? It is a library that like jQuery uses the $() shorthand among lots of other things. I believe you're just making use of the inherent javascript `prototype` property, which is something different than the actual library

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why getElementsByClassName does not work for me? What does it return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/why-getelementsbyclassname-does-not-work-for-me-what-does-it-return)

Comment: But can you tell me when i use document.getElementsByClassName('clck'); its not working instead of this if i use document.getElementById('clck'); then its working.

Comment: @Tushky That's because document.getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object. Check it out here: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

> "Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names."

opnpopup is an array containing all elements with class `clck`. You can't bind events on arrays.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var popup = new Popup();

    var opnpopup = document.getElementsByClassName('clck');

    for ( index = 0; index < opnpopup.length; index++ )
       opnpopup[ index ].addEventListener('click', function() {
         popup.openPopup();
      });

    var cnclpopup = document.getElementById('cancel');
    cnclpopup.addEventListener('click', function() {
        popup.closePopup();
    });
}
```

This code should work, so you bind the click event to all elements in this array.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but write now what happening the popup is displaying but when I click on cancel button the popup is not closing.

Comment: Yes I got the 
TypeError: opnpopup[index].addEventListener is not a function.